# Will LAMP meet the following needs?

Tags: lamp

I remember a few years back, when I had a web-site I wanted to develop, that many people recommended I go the LAMP route. Unfortunately, I never got around to studying/practicing that.

I'm currently revisiting the web-site idea.

The web-site will be dynamic, transactional, and hopefully end up with around 1,000,000 pv/mo and 300,000 members within 18 months. Will LAMP adequately support a site like that (i.e. have you seen it under a site with those specs)?

Regarding PHP: I need to expand upon skills that will make me more marketable in the job market, i.e. would sticking with PHP make me more marketable, or are there studies suggesting another language/script would be more useful?

Comment: Yes, I've seen LAMP perform well, even under much higher loads. In all, the bottleneck generally won't be the underlying technology used, but the business logic will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, that this depends much more on your programming proficiency in the language of your choosing, than following the latest trend. If you feel comfortable with a certain environment you might want to stick to that. It reduces the probability of errors and makes development easier and faster.

That said, the answer to your question would be, that I consider the lower part of the LAMP stack (Linux, Apache, MySQL) still a very viable choice. As for the language: Possible alternatives might be [Rails](http://www.rubyonrails.org/), [Grails](http://www.grails.org/), [Python](http://www.python.org/), [GWT](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/), for larger applications [Spring Web MVC](http://www.springsource.org/), or even [Perl](http://www.perl.org/), if you feel comfortable with it. The list is pretty much endless.

Comment: Since I don't have PHP experience, the language choice is open. Given, however, that I recently graduated with my CS degree and need to find work, the choice of language I learn needs to serve the dual purpose of web-site and employability. The following link points toward using C# and asp.net: [link](http://www.indeed.com/jobtrends?q=php%2C+python%2C+C%23%2C+asp.net%2C+ruby&l=)

Comment: In that case I would strongly recommend choosing either Java or ASP.Net since those languages are usually the most sought after skills with companies. Especially Java is often used in high end web server and networking applications.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, L/WAMP is still a popular platform to develop web applications on.

PHP, however, is a messy language. Python offers the about same level of dynamic programming but is much cleaner and more modular. ASP.NET with C# is even more structured, but you need a Windows stack and this is more complicated than copying some PHP files to your server.

Comment: On Windows, MVC has made a lot of progress to eliminate the complexity of server state and bring some of the gems of Ruby to ASP.Net

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on Rails is probably more "hot" than LAMP.

Comment: Hotness being the best metric for determining suitability, of course. :/

Comment: I agree that it's not. However, the original question title was _Is LAMP still a "hot" web develpment development scheme?_

Comment: Probably explains why the question was closed.